# Did Samsonite ever made LEGO studs? (1 x 1 round plates)

Tags: history

Having done some basic research it would seem that Samsonite stopped producing bricks before lego introduced studs, however I don’t fully understand the deal lego made with Samsonite, and I don’t fully trust the dates I found, so if anyone could explain it better I would be very appreciative.

As a side note, im curious particularly about the color of the studs. I’m attempting to collect every color of stud I reasonably can and iirc Samsonite used slightly different colors than lego, any info on other 1 x 1 pieces would also be helpful.

Comment: What is your definition of a ‘stud’? The little knob on top of a LEGO brick? Samsonite produced licensed LEGO bricks for many years for the North American market, before LEGO bought them out.

Comment: My bad, I didn’t clarify what exactly I meant. I’m talking about the 1 x 1 round plates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this listing, it appears Samsonite manufactured square 1x1 plates:
[image: Samsonite square 1x1 and 2x1 plate box]

However, I cannot find any record of round variations by Samsonite.

Comment: The set you've shown is from 1962 well before the introduction of round 1x1 plates in 1980

Comment: I'm aware, I just showed that as an example of the square plates. The fact that I couldn't find any round variations was unrelated to the picture :)